# How to change image after clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made scroll to bottom link on my image. It's a image of arrow pointing down. When you first visit site image of arrow is at bottom of page pointing down and when click on it it scrolls to bottom and ends up on top of page. Have can I implement that when arrow image is on top of page that it changes to image of arrow pointing up?

I have used this code to implement image and functionality of scrolling down.

.html

```
<div class="arrow"><a href="#" class="scroll-down" address="true">
<img src="https://blog.com/hubfs/Icon/arrow.png"> 
</a></div>
```

Supposed to replace it with src="https://blog.com/hubfs/Icon/arrowup.png">  and also add functionality when image changes to click on it and scroll to top

.js

```
 $(function() {
    $('.scroll-down').click (function() {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('div.me').offset().top }, 'fast');
      return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: If it's just an simple arrow then you should rotate it by 180 degrees via CSS instead of loading a new image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(function () {
        var clickedImg = false;
        var imageElement = $('#img_button');

        $('.scroll-down').click(function () {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
            clickedImg = !clickedImg;
            if (clickedImg) {
                imageElement.attr("src", 'arrow_down.png');
            } else {
                imageElement.attr("src", 'arrow_up.png');
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

With variable `clickedImg` we know when the image is clicked or not. If it is clicked, the arrow is down, if not, the arrow is up (in my example).

With this: `clickedImg = ! clickedImg;` we are toggling the value of the variable.

**Edit 1:**
I edited the above code to make it full `jQuery`.

**Edit 2:**
here is a [plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/8kmkcsuiGHXsqqyUY67s/)

**Edit 3:**
I belive this part of your code is not working:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('div.me').offset().top}, 'fast');
```

Because `$('div.me')` is `undefined`. Make sure that that element exists. If you comment this line, the code works. Fix that animate and you are set to go. Use my plunkr if it makes it easier for you. ;)

Comment: Thanks for comment. Should I put id='img_button' in my <div class="arrow"><a href="#" class="scroll-down" address="true">. I'm trying to do it but it's not working. @SrAxi

Comment: @user3599620 Hey! Yes, `#img_button` should be the img element. You could actually change it. But in your example should be this: `<img id="img_button" src="arrow.png">`.

Comment: I have tried for a while now but it's not working for me @SrAxi

Comment: @user3599620 I edited the code in order to make it pure jQuery. Could you please update your question with the full html and js code please? Are you getting errors in console?

Comment: @user3599620 Check my second edit. I made a plunkr, it's working fine. Let me know please! ;)

Comment: @user3599620 I think I found your error. Check Edit 3. ;)

Comment: Hi I had looked it and your code should work! But I think I have problem with my image src. I am working with CMS and trying to get image from there to display it. Have a look at my edited code, but still it supposed to work with this src with your code. Don't know why is not. $('div.me') is defined it is div until where scrolling will go. Have a look at my edit. @SrAxi

Comment: @user3599620 I could not access the path of the image from your example. But the main issue (How to change img on click) I believe has been resolved. Try with the src I used on my plunkr, if it works, then the issue is just your src.

Comment: Yes, it's working perfectly! So it is in my src. Thanks! @SrAxi

Comment: @user3599620 No problem mate! ;) I'm glad it got fixed!

Comment: but one little thing where to implement code to scroll back on top after changing image? :/ @SrAxi

Comment: @user3599620 I edited the code in my answer. You can scroll top before or after changing the image src. Check this line of code: `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138548/discussion-between-user3599620-and-sraxi).